# Cython passing a class to another class

Tags: cython

I want to pass a class (reference) to another class so that I can call methods on the class that is passed due a composition relationship between the classes.

This minimal example fails:

```
cdef class Klass:
    TheOtherKlass(self)

cdef class TheOtherKlass:
    def __init__(self, Klass):
        self.Klass = Klass
```

with

```
error undeclared name not builtin: self
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`self` is implicitly the first argument passed to a class method.

Your declaration:
`TheOtherKlass(self)`
isn't inside a method, so `self` is undefined in that scope.

In the example below, you see that you can call the constructor `TheOtherKlass(self)` using `self` as an argument, as long as you are inside a class method.

```
cdef class TheOtherKlass:
    def __init__(self, Klass):
        self.Klass = Klass


cdef class Klass:

    cdef TheOtherKlass myklass

    def __init__(self):               #Here self is passed as the first argument
        myklass = TheOtherKlass(self) #So it exists within the scope of __init__
```